# How we get user information from Active Directory using LDAP

Tags: authentication, sharepoint, active-directory

Try to login using an AD in network Sharepoint Application and give a access to a user using their Role.

Thank You !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use below PowerShell script to get all user information from active directory

```
$domain = Read-host "Enter a domain name"
$creds = Get-Credential
get-aduser -server $domain -filter * -Credential $creds
```

Comment: Thank you, but sorry I forgot to mention I am using a C#  on SharePoint application.

Comment: @KaNcHaNWaKoDiKaR I have found a link can try this one?
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19115.sharepoint-querying-active-directory-using-c-net.aspx